# Free HTML web page templates for Online Order Entry (receive thru email)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html

I want to create a new web page in my static html website for Online Order Entry (receive thru email) as per following details:

**User will select a particular product and press submit button from our web page, so the desired information will be received by us through an email.**

In fact, I don’t want to develop a comprehensive online shopping portal or cart.

*I just want a simple page that would send us the desired information through email only. Please advice me is there any ready made (free) template available on net so that I could use it.*

Please help / guide.

Regards.

Kamal

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see on your post tags, you're using Twitter Bootstrap. You can search [here](https://bootsnipp.com) for some free component templates.

Hope I can help you!